# jQuery Ajax Call inside of PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm clearly doing something wrong here, but I can't figure out why the Ajax isn't firing and instead insists upon a page load. The newBatable() fires fine, I just can't seem to get the vote to respect the ajax call.

HTML - not sure how to put html in here as code :/ - I feel dumb.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="batable1" action="vote.php" method="GET">
    <div id="success-vote-1"></div>
    <input type="radio" name="batableResult" value=" include ()" /> include ()<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="batableResult" value="require ()" />require ()<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="batableResult" value="both of above" />both of above<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="batableResult" value="None of above" />None of above<br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="vote(1)">Vote</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="batableId" id="batable-id" value="1"/>
</form>
```

JS - the console display everything I want, the php script processes everything nicely and functions perfectly, it is just it has to load the php in the browser so it's not using AJAX

```
/***************************************/
function newBatable() {
var batableData = $('#new-batable').serialize();
//console.log(batableData);
    $.ajax({
        url: "process.php",
        data: batableData,
        success: function(data){
            $('#success-new-batable').html(data);
        }
    });
}

/***************************************/
function vote(poll_id) {
//console.log(poll_id)
var batableId = "#batable" + poll_id;
//console.log(batableId)
var pollData = $(batableId).serialize();
//console.log(pollData);
    $.ajax({
        url: "vote.php",
        data: pollData,
        success: function(data){
            var batable_success_id = "#success-vote" + poll_id;
            $(batable_success_id).html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about attaching a click event via jquery to the button?

```
$(".btn").on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault();
    vote(1);
});
```

this would usually be placed in document .ready jquery in an external file or somewhere near the bottom of your page inside script tags.

Does this help?

Comment: Heck ya it did! :) Thank you! Should I change my jQuery though to be the modern event binding technique referenced @Quentin.

Comment: That link looks like its doing event binding via javascript instead of Jquery.  Persoanlly Im a big Jquery fan so Id stick with the above on.click but its really your preference.  just for reference the 'e.stopPropagation()' tells jquery to prevent the click from bubbling up onto other items on the page and 'e.preventDefault()' tells jquery to stop .btn from doing its default action (e.g with a link you click it, it will try and go somewhere but this will stop it from going to the href and force it to go with whatever is set via the click event in jquery)

Comment: Thank you - it works perfectly. The propagation made sense but I was confused on the default() - thanks for clarifying. I am sticking with jQuery ;)

Answer (score 3):

The submit button fires the JavaScript and then immediately submits the form.

If you are using `onclick`, then `return false` to stop that.

You would be better off using a [more modern event binding technique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#DOM_event_handler_List) though.

Comment: I'm looking at implementing the modern event binding technique but returning false did solve the problem - I used the technique from @SubstanceD

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using jQuery, as SubstanceD, you should use jQuery's on() method and stop the event propagation and prevent the default action (submitting the form).

I also noticed a possible bug in your code. It looks like there is a typo. You have

```
var batable_success_id = "#success-vote" + poll_id;
```

and `<div id="success-vote-1"></div>`. You have a dash after `vote` in the `div`'s ID while you are concatenating `batable_success_id` into `#success-vote1`, for example. So even if the AJAX call is made, it probably won't update your HTML like you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! I can't believe I missed the '-'. It definitely wouldn't have updated :/ - I'm also using the mouse to click the button - I hoped for some weird reason it would work after adding the dash - no avail. Thank you though - saved me a headache later!